# patchValue using the multiplication of two FormControl input in a FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In simple terms, I have a table bound to a FormArray. There is a input box that will take in two values, one from the same row and another as a 'default' value. I would like to perform a calculation on the values of these 2 and use the value derived from the result.

Using the `value` attribute in HTML of course does not work because when I `console.log` the formControl, the value is 0.

my HTML:

```
<ng-container formArrayName="cap_values">
    <tbody *ngFor="let item of capValues.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" formControlName="fdnTotalShares"
                (keyup.enter)="getFdnTotalShares(fdnVal.value)">
        </td>
        <td><input style="border: none; text-align: center" formControlName="fdnSharesPercent"
                value="{{Math.ceil(((100 / this.sumFdnTotalShares()) * this.capValues.value[i].fdnTotalShares) * 100.0) / 100.0 || 0}}"
                readonly="readonly">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

ts:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  fdnUnitPrice: [''],
  esopUnitPrice: [''],
  seedUnitPrice: [''],
  cap_values: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
    name: '',
    fdnTotalShares: '',
    fdnSharesPercent: '',
    fdnVal: '',
    esopNewShares: '',
    esopTotalShares: '',
    esopSharesPercent: '',
    esopTotalShareDiluted: '',
    esopSharesPercentDiluted: '',
    esopVal: '',
    seedNewShares: '',
    investment: '',
    seedTotalShares: '',
    seedSharesPercent: '',
    seedSharesDiluted: '',
    seedSharesPercentDiluted: '',
    seedTotalVal: ''
  }
  )])
})


get capValues() {
  return this.form.get('cap_values') as FormArray;
}
```

Is patchValue possible for this case? I need to get the value at index and then perform the calculation. Apologies if I am not clear enough.

Comment: Could you post `capValues` assignement? How is it created?

Comment: @LppEdd hi i have made edits to my post

Comment: Do you still need help on this?